# yahooquery return key error and HTTP 404 Not Found

Tags: python, dictionary, user-agent, yfinance

I am using the library yahooquery to extract a list of ticker for a specific sector.

I works fine until 200 hits but if I increase it further it start failing.

```
def screener():
    global ticker_list
    time.sleep(0.01)
    s = Screener()
    # data is a dictionary containing the keys passed to the function
    data = s.get_screeners('ms_energy', count=500)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['ms_energy']['quotes'])
    df = df.loc[:, "symbol"]
    s.available_screeners
    ticker_list = df.values.tolist()
    return ticker_list

screener()

KeyError: 'ms_energy'
```

or http 404 not found.

I have seen some comments on forcing the User-Agent header but I do not know where to add it within the library

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe yahoo doesn't have more pages/values.

Comment: maybe create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run to test problem.